# comparing the content of two char values

Tags: java

I'm trying to compare the content of two char values, but I'm getting the: "Cannot invoke equals(char) on the primitive type char" Error. I know the problems is on line 5 but I don't know how to overcome this problem, any ideas?

```
  public static int charPosition(String word, char letter){
       int answer=0, x;
       char [] charArray = word.toCharArray();
       for( x=0; x< word.length(); x++){
           if(charArray[x].equals(letter)){ answer =x;}
           else{ answer= -1;}
       }
        return answer;
   }
```

Comment: Use `==` instead of `equals`

Comment: as a tip, your loop seems to be faulty. If the character at position x is equal  to the given letter, the answer is set to x. But then the next iteration, when the character is not equal, the answer is set to -1 and x is lost.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When comparing `char`, you use `==`, not `.equals`. The latter is for comparing objects (like `String`s), not primitives like `char`.

So:

```
public static int charPosition(String word, char letter) {
    int answer = 0, x;
    char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
    for (x = 0; x < word.length(); x++) {
        if (charArray[x] == letter) {     // <−−−−−− Change is here
            answer = x;
        } else {
            answer = -1;
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

**But**, there's more wrong with that loop:

1. You need to terminate the loop when you find the character, and
2. You should start with `answer` set to `-1`, and
3. As long as you have an array, you may as well use its `length` instead of `String`'s `length()`:

So:

```
public static int charPosition(String word, char letter) {
    int answer = -1, x;
    char[] charArray = word.toCharArray();
    for (x = 0; x < charArray.length; x++) { // <−−−
        if (charArray[x] == letter) {        // <−−−
            answer = x;
            break;                           // <−−−
        }
    }
    return answer;
}
```

Comment: wow, thank you T.J, I changed the "equals" to "==" but I was still having issues. this code modification made a big difference!

Answer (score 3):

Char is a primitive type. It do not have methods that you can invoke from. To compare primitive types (`char`, `int`, `boolean`, `float`, `double`, etc) you should use `==`.

`.equals` is a method from the [Object](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html) class. The docs says:

> `equals(Object obj) : boolean`
>
> Indicates whether some other object is "equal to" this one.

When comparing strings you should use `.equals` because the class [String](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) inherits from Object.

Answer (score 1):

You have to use == operator to compare character or primitive data type. Equals method used for object and string comparison.

```
public static int charPosition(String word, char letter){
           int answer=0, x;
           char [] charArray = word.toCharArray();
           for( x=0; x< word.length(); x++){
               if(charArray[x]==letter){ answer =x; break;}
               else{ answer= -1;}
           }
            return answer;
       }
```

I hope this would be helpful.